# SLF4J config location for Maven-build JAR in Grails project running as WAR in Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, grails, log4j, slf4j

For my current web app I wrote a library in java which does some fancy backend tasks. All program output runs through log4j or to be more precise with slf4j. I did a special config like this

```
### Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %p %C{1} %M(): %m%n

### Logger1 ########################################
log4j.appender.Logger1=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.Logger1.MaxFileSize=100MB
log4j.appender.Logger1.MaxBackupIndex=50
log4j.appender.Logger1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.Logger1.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %p %C{1} %M(): %m%n
log4j.appender.Logger1.File=logs/Logger1.log
log4j.logger.com.example.Logger1=INFO,Logger1

# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, console
```

So the Logger1 class should go into logs/Logger1.log. I defined every dependencies in maven to integrate SLF4J and log4j and the config is put to ROOT_OF_SOURCE_CODE/config/log3j.configuration. When I start the main method of this library in my IDE IntelliJ IDEA everything works fine, the log file is created and I get the messages there.

Now my main web app is a grails project which uses my jar library build by maven. So I defined the dependencies in grails for this lib.

**PROBLEM:** When I build the war out of my grails app and deploy it there is no output into the Logger1.log file anymore, this file isn't even created.

If I check out the WEB-INF/lib directory and locate my library and if I extract the lib jar, then there is no log4j.properties file included anymore. So I copied the file to WEB-INF and WEB-INF/classes and also in the lib directory of my grails app, but I still can't get any logging done.

**What I would like to know:** where does java look for the config file if I use slf4j in a library jar which is referred in a grails web-app which runs in a tomcat server?

**What I would expect:** I would like to define in my tomcat where a global slf4j config stays and I would like to have this outside of any web app directory. I also would like to have the log files outside the web app directory. Is this possible?

Thanks for any help

Comment: do you know http://logback.qos.ch/reasonsToSwitch.html

Comment: thanks for this advice, I would consider this in the near feature. I think my problem would be the same with logback, mh?

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to place the log4j.properties file correctly, sorry for bothering you...

I had a look in the war file and saw that the grails packageing porcess wasn't adding the config file automatically. Also my library jar file which was in the grails WAR file didn't contain the log4j.properties file.

So I put my log4j.properties to /DIR_OF_YOUR_TOMCAT_INSTALL/lib/log4j.properties and used absolute paths in the log4j.properties for my RollingFileAppenders. Now everything works fine..

Thanks for reading

**Edit:**

A way more elegant way is to edit the Config.groovy file. Just add your rules for appenders or PatternLayouts in this file - also for specific classes which are compiled into external JAR files!